NGinx Proxy Pass Not Executing
I am running a very simple Flask webserver:
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/get_latest_api_version', methods=['GET'])
def get_latest_api_version():
    return "3.0.0"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')

That is being called via python3 -m gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app --log-level "debug" (in a tmux session).
I am also running nginx as a systemd process with the following relevant configuration:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name problemsite.ca;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/problemsite.ca/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/problemsite.ca/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

The Problem
Nginx is having some sort of unexplained communication issues with the gunicorn server when receiving the incoming requests and returning bad gateway calls. A sample error message:
<IP SOURCE> - - [04/May/2024:20:58:31 +0000] "GET /api/get_latest_api_version HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "curl/7.68.0"
From the request curl -X 'GET' 'https://problemsite.ca/api/get_latest_api_version' -H 'accept: application/json'
Other Info

Nginx version: nginx/1.14.1
Gunicorn version: gunicorn==21.2.0
Flask version: Flask==2.0.3
Locally executing curl -X 'GET' 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/get_latest_api_version' -H 'accept: application/json' returns a response
The SSL certificate and domain name are working
Nginx is running and listening to the 443 requests evident by incoming error logs when external error requests are coming in
There are zero debug logs in the gunicorn server output when the external API requests are being made, despite requests being captured in nginx error logs
Server is running on a free instance of Oracle computer with Oracle Linux 8
There are no other web servers (that I know of) running that may be causing conflicts
I've run the following commands in totality from the fresh VM state to now:
Nginx is running as a systemd process
Gunicorn is running locally in a terminal on the base machine
Everything is running as root
I've run the following commands in totality:

pip3 install flask gunicorn
yum install -y nginx tmux
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh /tmp/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
dnf install -y snapd
systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
systemctl start snapd
ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
snap install core
snap refresh core
snap install --classic certbot
ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=443/tcp
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=5000/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
certbot certonly --standalone -d "problemsite.ca" --non-interactive --agree-tos -m "problem@problemsite.ca"
<copy SSL part to nginx config>
systemctl enable nginx
systemctl restart nginx
<create app.py file>

What Else I've Tried

Adding a final '/' to the nginx SSL proxy pass site (proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;)
Changing the gunicorn server to listen to 127.0.0.1 and/or localhost and/or addresses of other interfaces
Changing the proxy pass IP to localhost and/or 0.0.0.0 and/or other addresses of other interfaces
Attempted to make the external API call from multiple different machines, each with the same error, indicating it's server-side related


What happens when you dropt all the ssl/tls stuff in nginx? For testing purpose, switch everything to http. Do you have SELinux enabled?

Same issue - something in nginx is not working properly, like the proxy pass directive is getting ignored. SELinux is enabled

Disabling that SELinux cancer seems to have fixed it - thank you so much!

When you have flask running behind a proxy you need to make sure to tell Flask its behind a proxy, as per documentation:
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix

app = Flask(__name__)

# x_for: X-Forwarded-For
# x_proto: X-Forwarded-Proto
# x_host: X-Forwarded-Host
# x_prefix: X-Forwarded-Prefix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_proto=1, x_host=1, x_prefix=1)

and add proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /; to your location / in your nginx configuration.
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /;  
}

Make sure to restart or reload nginx configuration and gunicorn.

Thanks for the response, unfortunately this suggestion did not work. Same bad gateway error with no logs from the gunicorn server (when requests are made externally)
